# Output source file name

Tags: code-golf, file-system

Write a program that prints the name of its source file. REPL environments are not allowed for this challenge. Your code must work in any file that your language's interpreter will accept. Your answer must also be a full program, not just a function. The source code's file extension must be printed. Leading or trailing newline are both optional. This is a code golf, so shortest answer wins. The winner will be chosen on September 2nd, 2016.

Comment: Possibly dupe of the cheating quine challenge? Idk though.

Comment: @Mego that question asks to actually reverse the charge filename in the file system. This is just printing the file name. So not a duplicate

Comment: @vikarjramun Reading the file name is a significant part of the challenge. This is a trivial subset of that challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 3 bytes

```
"zp
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=Inpw&input=)

This actually *does* work in the online interpreter somehow. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Explanation:

The 'z' register is predefined to the source file of the program, and `p` pastes from whatever register you tell it to. `P` would also work, and not cause any different output.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 7

```
echo $0
```

So trivial, I have to type in this text to make the answer long enough.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 23 bytes

```c
main(){puts(__FILE__);}
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/15AST1)